# Add keys from dicts (in column) to new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a 'budgetYearMap' column, which has 1-3 key-value pairs for each record. I'm a bit stuck as to how I'm supposed to make a new column containing only the keys of the "budgetYearMap" column.

Sample data below:

```
df_sample = pd.DataFrame({'identifier': ['BBI-2016-D02', 'BBI-2016-D03', 'BBI-2016-D04', 'BBI-2016-D05', 'BBI-2016-D06'],
                    'callIdentifier': ['H2020-BBI-JTI-2016', 'H2020-BBI-JTI-2016', 'H2020-BBI-JTI-2016', 'H2020-BBI-JTI-2016', 'H2020-BBI-JTI-2016'],
                    'budgetYearMap': [{'0': 188650000}, {'2017': 188650000}, {'2015': 188650000}, {'2014': 188650000}, {'2020': 188650000, '2014': 188650000, '2012': 188650000}]
                    })
```

First I tried to extract the keys by position, then make a list out of them and add the list to the dataframe. As some records contained multiple keys (I then found out), this approach failed.

```
all_keys = [i for s in [list(d.keys()) for d in df_sample.budgetYearMap] for i in s]
df_TD_selected['budgetYear'] = all_keys
```

My problem is that extracting the keys by "name" wouldn't work either, given that the names of the keys are variable, and I do not know the set of years in advance. The data set will keep growing. It can be either 0 or a year within the 2000 range now, but in the future more years will be added.

My desired output would be:

```
df_output = pd.DataFrame({'identifier': ['BBI-2016-D02', 'BBI-2016-D03', 'BBI-2016-D04', 'BBI-2016-D05', 'BBI-2016-D06'],
                    'callIdentifier': ['H2020-BBI-JTI-2016', 'H2020-BBI-JTI-2016', 'H2020-BBI-JTI-2016', 'H2020-BBI-JTI-2016', 'H2020-BBI-JTI-2016'],
                    'Year': ['0', '2017', '2015', '2014', '2020, 2014, 2012']
                    })
```

Any idea how I should approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect pipeline use-case.

```
df = (
    df_sample
    .assign(Year = df_sample['budgetYearMap'].apply(lambda s: list(s.keys())))
    .drop(columns = ['budgetYearMap'])
)
```

.assign creates a new column which takes the 'budgetYearMap' Series and applies the lambda function to it. This returns the dictionary's keys in a list. If you prefer a string (as in your desired output), simply replace the lambda function with

```
lambda s: ', '.join(list(s.keys()))
```

Comment: Not sure why, but I get a SyntaxError when I run this: unexpected EOF while parsing.

Comment: Missed a bracket for the .drop() command - now it should work.

Comment: And a closing bracket for the .assign() command. It works perfectly, thanks!